# BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath returning null value

Tags: c#, asp.net

why the value of **display** is null

```
 public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
{
    var display = BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(
                    _virtualPath, typeof(Page)) as IDisplay;
    return display;
}
```

the value of _virtualPath is '~/RegisterUser.aspx' of type string

Comment: Change `as` to a cast and see if you get a cast exception.

Comment: yes it giving me cast exception :(

Comment: What does the exception day?

Comment: its showing this exeption "The type 'IDisplay' exists in both 'Lyrikz.dll' and 'App_Code.hxrjn1eh.dll"

Answer (score 0):

In your page codebehind inherits from IDisplay sample:

```
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class secondpage: System.Web.UI.Page, **IDisplay**     <--------------------
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    } 
}
```